# Embedded view doesn't appear in node

Tags: views, nodes

I have node  **golosuizaprognoz_lenta** with hidden field **argument-lenta**, node **golosuizaprognoz** with field **field_argument**, view of table with Rating wiget:

[image]

The node have title with date, for example **21/06/14 Голосуй за прогноз!!!**

I need that in node was view only with date equal date in title.

What I have done:

I add to node **golosuizaprognoz_lenta** hidden field **argument-lenta** where I add url of result node, for example **210614-golosuy-za-prognoz**.

I make EVA display:

[image]

with contextual filter:

[image]

[image]

when I insert content of field **field_argument** wich equal of url node  **golosuizaprognoz_lenta** , for example [image] all OK, I get what I want, but in node I have no this view (without contectual filters view is shown so I attached it).

How I need to fit contextual filters that in node I will see only views with content wich have field **field_argument** wich equal of url node  **golosuizaprognoz_lenta**.

http://myforecast.esy.es/**210614-golosuy-za-prognoz**/

[image]

Comment: are you saying the contextual filter itself does not work, or are you trying to get the url of the content to include the date (example.com/210614-golosuy-za-prognoz)

Comment: i say the contextual filter itself does not work.

Comment: but it works in Views, with a contextual filter defined?

Comment: yes, Geoff, in view's preview all is OK. temporarly I have resolved this issue - choosed php in contextual filters and insert return array_pop(explode('/',drupal_get_path_alias()));. All work perfectly, but may be exists more elegant decision?

Comment: the only other way I can think of would be to separate the content into a sub-folder as part of it's url (i.e. example.com/golosuy-za-prognoz/210614, example.com/golosuy-za-prognoz/120214, etc). This should be accessible directly

Comment: Geoff, But how can I divide it if the title is "21/06/14 Голосуй за прогноз!!!" => url: "210614-golosuy-za-prognoz"

Comment: By using Auto Node Title (https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle). This will generate automatic node titles, and allows PHP to define that title. Using str_replace (http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) you can remove the slashes replacing them with nothing, creating the desired effect. Then use a token in the title for the rest of it

Comment: ou, i forgot about it (nodetitle). Thank you, Geoff!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this by using [Auto Node Title](http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle) . This will generate automatic node titles, and allows PHP to define that title. Using [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)  you can remove the slashes from a date field and replacing them with nothing, creating the desired effect. Then use a token or static text in the title for the rest of it

> "auto_nodetitle" is a small and efficient module that allows hiding of
>   the content title field in the form. To prevent empty content title
>   fields one can configure it to generate the title by a given pattern.